# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with ... Reason: PowerMock internal error when modifying method.

Tags: java, junit, ivy, powermock

I'm running a unit test that I've had working in the past, and suddenly this new error just started showing up. It appears to be a problem with PowerMock? Any idea what's up here?

My project depends on lots of other projects that are resolved using Ivy. Here's a log message of what's happening:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.test.MyTestClass. Reason: PowerMock internal error when modifying method.
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:207)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:145)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:210)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:145)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:133)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PowerMock internal error when modifying method.
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:304)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:192)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:91)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1385)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:75)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:203)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: mockStatic(..) is not found in org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
    at javassist.CtClassType.getMethod(CtClassType.java:1130)
    at javassist.expr.MethodCall.getMethod(MethodCall.java:115)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:283)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this turned out to be a version conflict with the version of PowerMock being used by a project my main project depended on.

i.e. There were 2 versions of PowerMock that were being used - an older one by a dependent project, and a newer one by my main project.

To fix it, I just had to update the PowerMock version used by my other project.

e.g In my ivy.xml, I updated my PowerMock version to 1.5.4 and it seemed to fix the problem:

```
<dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-core" rev="1.5.4" conf="master->default" />
<dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-api-mockito" rev="1.5.4" conf="master->default" />
<dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-module-junit4" rev="1.5.4" conf="master->default" />
```

Comment: I upgraded the version of PowerMock in my pom file from 1.4.12 to 1.5 but it started to give more test case failures. Any clue?

Comment: No idea.... this fixed it for me - but I'm not sure how big a version jump it was between PowerMock versions now... Maybe mine was more minor (e.g. 1.5 to 1.5.4?)